# DRF and Django Filters - filter releated objects

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-filters

I've got two models:

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Note(models.Model):
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Both have serializers:

```
class NoteSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'

class UserSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Note
        fields = '__all__'

    notes = NoteSerializer(
        many=True,
        read_only=True,
    )
```

Now, I need to an endpoint that will return a JSON with the list of users with related notes for each one of them.

The trick here is to be able to filter those notes by a date range. I imagine the URL would look like this:

```
/api/clients/?range=month&date=2019-03
```

This translates to: "give me a list of all users with their related notes with  timestamp between 2019-03-01 and 2019-04-1.

And the question is: what's the best approach to accomplish that using Django Filters?

Comment: Not related to django-filter, but you will first need to add a `ForeignKey` field to your `Note` model to be able to filter those objects by user...

Comment: Yes, sorry. It is there. The code I shared is just to illustrate the issue. I've correct it. Thanks!